# How to change the coding for XML

Tags: excel, vba

[In the image the value under "open" inside red circle 749.10 i want in my excel sheet.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ddzvh.jpg) I am doing my project work where i need this XML code for fast work.

I did understand the excel vba coding write this code my own, i have tried so much but i am unable to do the same work in "XML" way.

```
Sub JJ()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim hdoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim ha, hb, hc, hd As String


    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=HAL"
    Do While IE.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Loop

    Set hdoc = IE.document

    ha = hdoc.getElementById("open").innerText
    Range("K2").Value = ha

   IE.Quit

End Sub
```

I expected the working XML code for same work

Comment: What exact data you need to retrieve from the webpage? Better to add a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are saying you want to convert to xmlhttp request. Some of the content is javascript rendered but the value you want is also present in a div as json.

You can see that the id you are targeting is empty in the response as the content requires javascript to populate:

[image]

However, the same info is present elsewhere in a `div`:

[image]

You can parse out the desired value from that json using a json parser. I use [jsonconverter.bas](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-JSON/blob/master/JsonConverter.bas). After adding the `.bas` to your project you need to go `VBE > Tools > References > Add a reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime`. You also need a reference for `Microsoft HTML Object Library`. When you examine the json response with a [json viewer](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) you will see the structure. `{}` indicates a dictionary accessed by key; `[]` indicates a collection accessed by index and the values with ■ are string literals.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL As String = "https://www.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=HAL"
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, json As Object
    Set html = New HTMLDocument
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .Send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responsetext
    End With
    Set json = jsonconverter.ParseJson(html.getElementById("responseDiv").innerText)
    Debug.Print json("data")(1)("open")
End Sub
```

---

Here is a reduced view of the json:

[image]

Comment: Please tell me the way to see json responce. Your answer helped me my problem is solved.

Comment: https://jsoneditoronline.org/?#right=local.dokudo&left=local.cisusu @JugalKishor

Comment: Thanks QHarr i have a problem to get inner text in nested json will you help me there, the json code is - https://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/3ic4, i want to print json>data>1>CH_CLOSING_PRICE.

Comment: what have you tried? You use (number) to index for collection and ("key...") to access dictionary items

Comment: hii QHarr lets took this one  the json response is "https://www.nseindia.com/api/historical/cm/equity?symbol=DIVISLAB" and iam trying

Comment: Sub JnewFast()
Dim req As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim URL As String, ws As Worksheet
Dim json As Object
Dim r, r1, r2, r3 As String
URL = "https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=DIVISLAB"
With req
.Open "GET", URL, False
.send
Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)
End With

r = json("priceInfo")("lastPrice")
r1 = json("priceInfo")("intraDayHighLow")("min")
    r2 = json("priceInfo")("intraDayHighLow")("max")
    r3 = json("priceInfo")("close")
    Debug.Print r, r1, r2, r3

End Sub

Comment: Sorry the JSON response is https://www.nseindia.com/api/quote-equity?symbol=DIVISLAB

Comment: what number are you after from response?